# Are there restrictions on pawn promotion if two pawns are on the same column?

Tags: chess, end-game

I was playing white and I had one pawn at a7 and the other at a6. My opponent didn't let me promote the pawn to a Queen stating that when two pawns are in the same column then the pawn doesn't get promoted.

Is this correct? If so, then what happens to a pawn which reaches a8? Does that become useless?

[image]

Comment: I've never heard if that rule, and looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promotion_%28chess%29 it doesn't seem to be listed...

Comment: btw: if you had a pawn on a7 and a pawn on a6 they're on the same _file_ (or column) not the same row

Answer (score 29):

Your friend was wrong.  There is no rule preventing a pawn from being promoted outside the normal move restriction rules (e.g. you can't leave your king in check).

Answer (score 5):

I am a chess arbiter and I can confirm that this rule does *not* exist whatsoever in the FIDE rules of chess. The only restriction to promotion is if it's an illegal move.

Answer (score 4):

Some players will do anything to try to prevent them losing...

From the position above, white promotes and black may as well resign. White can make a 2nd queen and give one of them up if necessary to prevent black's attack with the d and e pawns.
You won't even need to do that though. If black moves Ke4 his pawn on d5 is pinned, if he plays d5-d4 you go Qf3+ and if he plays Ke6 you just go Qc6+. Anything else and you just capture on d5.

Answer (score 1):

There is never any difference in restrictions when a pawn queens, regarding pawns in the same file behind it. 
(Of course you can't overtake the pawn in front)
[my rating: 1920]

Comment: Difference between what? I'm not sure how this is responding to the question.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. There is never any difference in restrictions when a pawn queens, regarding pawns in the same file behind it.